# Rails check if field value is the default value for that field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, default

I have a field named `number` on the `Address` model, which has a default of `0` set at database level. If I do `Address.new.number`, I will get `0` back.

Now, I want to trigger a `before_create` callback only if `number != <default value>`. So, I will have `before_create :callback, unless: <condition>`. How can I check this using some Rails "logic"? I know I can compare to `0`, but I'd rather compare to a dynamical value, as retrieved by Rails.

Comment: "but I'd rather compare to a dynamical value" -- What do you mean here? What else are you trying to compare it with?

Comment: Instead of checking whether `number != 0`, I'd rather check whether `number != Address.default_for_number`, or something alike.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Default values are accessible in [`Address.column_defaults`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/column_defaults) as a hash of `{"column" => default}`:

```
Address.column_defaults
#=> {"number" => 0, "street" => nil, ...}
```

You can also use the [`<attribute>_changed?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) methods Rails provides. This will be `false` unless you initialize the object with a non-default value.

```
Address.new.number_changed? #=> false
Address.new(number: 1).number_changed? #=> true
```

So your `before_create` can look like:

```
before_create :callback, if: :number_changed?
```

Comment: Looks neat, but If I change it to a value, then back to the default one, I guess it won't work as expected. I'd use something foolproof.

Comment: @AndreiHorak Found it!

Comment: Also, if you set the attribute to something non-default and then back to the default, `*_changed?` will revert to reporting `false`.

Comment: Seems that I've missed that obvious `column_defaults`. And didn't know about `*_changed?` reverting back. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

what about using the columns has?

```
Address.columns_hash['number'].default
```

should give you want

so maybe something like this

```
before_create :callback, unless: Proc.new { |address| address.number == Address.columns_hash['number'].default }
```

But this seems kinda odd over using something like `number_changed?`